# await / async issues

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, async-await, .net-4.5

I'm working on Windows 8 CP and discovered that in my app, I'm unable to properly get the new async/await mechanism to work.

This method I am showing you will work when run as a UnitTest (called from a unit test) but when ran normally, it DOES NOT WORK!

```
StreamSocket _client;

private void Start() {
     SomeMethod();
     SomeOtherMethod();
}

private async void SomeMethod(string sample)
{
    var request = new GetSampleRequestObject(sample);
    byte[] payload = ConvertToByteArray(request, Encoding.UTF8);

    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(_client.OutputStream);
    writer.WriteBytes(payload);
    await writer.StoreAsync(); // <--- after this executes, it exits the method and continues
    await writer.FlushAsync(); // <--- breakpoint never reaches here, instead
    writer.DetachStream();
}

private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    string hello = "hello"; // <--- it skips everything and reaches here!
}
```

What gives?

Comment: What does it do instead of work? How does it behave?

Comment: See inline comments showing execution.

Comment: An `async void` method is "fire and forget" - when you call it, it starts executing asynchronously, and returns to the caller immediately. This is by design. If you want to wait for it to complete, you need to make it return a `Task`, and `await` on that in the caller.

Comment: Yep, but the problem is when I do that, it gets stuck on the first await method, even though the message was sent.

Comment: I also created a separate metro app and the same code works. Wierd.

Comment: All I can tell you is that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you post your unit test code as well?

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to put await in front of your initial SomeMethod call in the Start function:

`await SomeMethod();`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. But with the await keyword it should behave the same in both situations. If you call an async function/method it returns to the caller when it reaches the first line that also has an await at the beginning (most of the time if the operation in question is not finished immediately).

Comment: Maybe that in your unit tests the async operations you await return immediately so they are not really asynchronously executed. During normal runs they really do something that takes a little bit of time.

Comment: If you're using the async unit test support, then it works because it gets the test back as a Task and then waits on it to complete (AFAIK)

Comment: You can't `await` an `async` method that returns `void`. What exactly would you be awaiting?

Answer (score 2):

I think Daniel Schlößer's answer may has some other problem.
Here are my improved method:

```
private async void Start() {
    await SomeMethod();
    SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

An async function should be called with "await" at the beginning surely. But the function which use async function should be signed "async" as well.

That's my point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like you want SomeMethod to complete before calling SomeOtherMethod, you need to have it return a Task and wait on that task to complete.  All you need to do is change the 'async void' in the declaration to 'async Task' and then in the Start method, change the caller to SomeMethod().Wait();

As it stands, since you're not waiting for anything about the task to complete, once the method exits (hitting the first await), there's nothing to 'block' anything else on it having completed.

Using 'async void' means you don't care when it completes (or perhaps even *if* it completes).  If you do care, you need to use 'async Task' and then use that appropriately.

Not sure if it'll help explain, but here's a blog post I did on the subject:

http://blog.sublogic.com/2012/03/06/async-lesson-2-of-n-async-void-probably-isnt-what-you-want/

Comment: You should never call `Wait()` on the UI thread. Instead, you should `await` the result.

Comment: agreed, sorry I missed that this was happening on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit:

```
StreamSocket _client;

private async Task Start() {
    await SomeMethod();
     SomeOtherMethod();
}

private async Task SomeMethod(string sample)
{
    var request = new GetSampleRequestObject(sample);
    byte[] payload = ConvertToByteArray(request, Encoding.UTF8);

    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(_client.OutputStream);
    writer.WriteBytes(payload);
    await writer.StoreAsync(); // <--- after this executes, it exits the method and continues
    await writer.FlushAsync(); // <--- breakpoint never reaches here, instead
    writer.DetachStream();
}

private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    string hello = "hello"; // <--- it skips everything and reaches here!
}
```

I hope help you